Finding an unknown length with intersecting circles
Question: Two circles with centers $O_1$ and $O_2$ intersect at points $A$ and $B$. The line segment $AO_1$ intersects the circle centered at $O_2$ at point $N$, and the line segment $AO_2$ intersects the circle centered at $O_1$ at point $M$. Given that $MN = 4$, $NK = 6$, and $KO_1 = 3$, find the square of the length of $\overline{O_1 O_2}$.

In exam, this is the solution that I came up with:
Consider the coordinate space with basis vectors $\overrightarrow{KO_1}=\vec{a}$ and $\overrightarrow{KM}=\vec{b}$. Then, we can say that:

$K$ has coordinates $(0,0)$
$O_1$ has coordinates $(1,0)$
$N$ has coordinates $\left(0, \frac{3}{5} \right)$
$M$ has coordinates $(0,1)$
$O_2$ has coordinates $(t,0)$ for some constant $t$.
$|\vec{a}|=3$ and $|\vec{b}|=10$

Since we know that $O_1 N \cap O_2 M=A$, it is easy to determine that the coordinates of $A$ are $\left(\frac{2t}{5-3t}, \frac{3-3t}{5-3t} \right)$.
Now, considering the radii of $O_1$ and $O_2$, we have the following:

Considering the radius of $O_1$ yields $$\left| \overrightarrow{O_1 A} \right|=\left| \overrightarrow{O_1 M} \right|$$ $$\left|\frac{5t-5}{5-3t} \vec{a}+\frac{3-3t}{5-3t} \vec{b} \right|=\left|\vec{a}-\vec{b} \right|$$ $$|t-1| \cdot |5 \vec{a}-3 \vec{b}|=|5-3t| \cdot |\vec{a}-\vec{b}|$$ Squaring both sides yields $$(t-1)^2 (25|\vec{a}|^2-30 \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}+9|\vec{b}|^2)=(5-3t)^2 (|\vec{a}|^2-2 \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}+|\vec{b}|^2)$$ $$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}=\frac{36t^2+255t-400}{3t^2-5}$$

Considering the radius of $O_2$ yields $$\left|\overrightarrow{O_2 A} \right|=\left|\overrightarrow{O_2 N} \right|$$ $$\left| \frac{3t^2-3t}{5-3t} \vec{a}+\frac{3-3t}{5-3t} \vec{b} \right|=\left|t \vec{a}-\frac{3}{5} \vec{b} \right|$$ $$|(3t^2-3t) \vec{a}+(3-3t) \vec{b}|=|5-3t| \cdot \left|t\vec{a}-\frac{3}{5} \vec{b} \right|$$ $$|t-1| \cdot |3t\vec{a}-3 \vec{b}|=|5-3t| \cdot \left|t \vec{a}-\frac{3}{5} \vec{b} \right|$$ Squaring both sides yields $$(t-1)^2 \left(9t^2 |\vec{a}|^2 -18t \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}+9|\vec{b}|^2 \right)=(5-3t)^2 \left(t^2 |\vec{a}|^2-\frac{6}{5}t \vec{a} \cdot \vec{b} +\frac{9}{25} |\vec{b}|^2 \right)$$ $$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}=\frac{15(3t^2+12t-20)}{3t^2-5}$$


Now that we have two different expressions for $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{b}$, we can set them equal to each other: $$\frac{36t^2+255t-400}{3t^2-5}=\frac{15(3t^2+12t-20)}{3t^2-5}$$  Solving this yields $t=\frac{5}{3}$ and $t=\frac{20}{3}$. However, if $t=\frac{5}{3}$, then the coordinates of $A$ are undefined, so we reject this solution.
Therefore, $\overrightarrow{KO_2}=\frac{20}{3} \vec{a} \implies \left|\overrightarrow{KO_2} \right|=\frac{20}{3} \left|\vec{a} \right|=20$.
To conclude, $O_1 O_2=20-3=17$, making the answer $17^2=\boxed{289}$.

However, I am not satisfied with this solution as it is bashy and inelegant. That being said, I don't know how to solve this synthetically.

I tried applying Menelaus' theorem on $\triangle MKO_2$ and $\triangle AO_1 O_2$, but didn't see much to do after.
I also tried applying Ceva's theorem on $\triangle MKO_2$ due to the fact that $\overline{KO_2}$ and $\overline{MK}$ are already "split" by $O_1$ and $N$ (respectively), but I didn't know how to deal with side $\overline{MO_2}$.
Finally, I thought of letting $T$ be the point where the line through $M$ parallel to $\overline{AO_1}$ meets $\overline{KO_2}$.

Then, I noticed that $\triangle NO_1 K \sim \triangle MTK$ and $\triangle MTO_2 \sim \triangle AO_1 O_2$. However, after I made the similarity ratios, it was just useless length bashing from then on out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!


Based on your solution, I believe $K$ is the intersection of $MN$ and $O_1O_2$, so I assumed that and proceeded.
Let's denote $P,Q$ be the midpoints of $AM,AN$ respectively. It can be seen easily that $O_1P \perp AO_2$ and $O_2Q \perp AO_1$ since $\triangle O_1 AM$ and $\triangle O_2 AN$ are isosceles. Therefore, $PO_2O_1Q$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. You can easily see that $MN \parallel PQ$ by Thales's theorem. Thus $\angle ANM = \angle AQP = \angle AO_2O_1$. In particular, this tells you that $MNO_1O_2$ is also a cyclic quadrilateral. Using the power of point, you will have
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\label{my_eq} KM \cdot KN = KO_1\cdot KO_2\end{equation}
Since $KN=6, KM=NM+NK=10$, we must have
$$KO_2 = \dfrac{KM\cdot KN}{KO_1} = \dfrac{6\cdot 10}{3}=20 $$
Then $O_1O_2=KO_2 - KO_1=17$, which means $O_1O_2^2=289$.
Remark: If you don't know power of a point, identity $\eqref{my_eq}$ also follows from the fact that $M,N,O_1,O_2$ are concyclic and thus $\triangle KO_1M \sim KNO_2.$

As an aside, I added a solution that proves the cyclic quad directly.

This solution follows Tri's, where the crux is to show that $O_1O_2 MN$ is a cyclic quad.
My contribution is to prove this directly (no further construction needed) via Power of a Point at $A$. Observe that:
$$ AO_1 \cdot AN = AO_1 (2 \cdot AO_2 \cdot  \cos \angle O_1 A O_2 ) = AO_2  ( 2 \cdot AO_1 \cdot  \cos \angle O_1 A O_2) = AO_2 \cdot AM. $$
Hence $O_1O_2MN$ is a cyclic quad.
Then, follow Tri's solution to calculate $O_1O_2$ from the lengths given.

Note: Applying cosine rule,
$$A O_1 (2 \cdot AO_2 \cdot  \cos \angle O_1 A O_2 ) = AO_1^2 + AO_2^2 - O_1O_2^2. $$
In a previous iteration of this solution, I showed that both terms were equal to this value, which took more work.

Nice! I initially thought this may be sort of direct from power of point but couldn't figure out it can work this way.

@Tri Haha, I've decided to replace my solution with the observation about your solution, as it gives me a one-liner. $\quad$ I somewhat prefer your solution because it leads us to discover the cyclic quad, whereas mine (esp the previous version) relied on knowing it's cyclic to then try to prove it. This version at least establishes that $AM : AN = AO_1 : AO_2$.
